# Bold font with bold weight in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uifont

I have a design that uses Helvetica-Bold font with a weight of bold: i'm trying to explain myself: a bold font, which can be set also to bold. But in iOS, trying to make a font bold, over and over again i found as answer to just use the bold font from a given family. And i want to put that font to bold again, to be... "bolder"?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest solution for you, if you're using `-drawAtPoint:withFont:` is to just call the method twice with the x-position offset by 1 pixel on the second call.  It won't be perfect (the spacing might be a bit messed up) but maybe it's good enough for you if you're not doing anything too exacting?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this thing out. Drawing the text twice with a 1 pixel offset is not too bad, but as you said the spacing get's really messed. Any other workaround?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is drawing each character separately and do the spacing yourself, but getting that to work well might take more time (both designing and at runtime) than you're willing to sacrifice.  Would increasing the font size just a little bit be sufficient to make the text "stand out" more rather than making it bolder?

Comment: Although the char count is kind of fixed, as you said it would be allot of trouble drawing them one by one. I'll try with a bigger size or, well, another font. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you can do it with the tools you have already but I do know that you can do it with FontLabel and your prepared "Bolder" Font.

So, you do a "special font" that is Helvetica in the bold level you want and embed it with FontLabel

Take a look: [Font Label](https://github.com/zynga/FontLabel)

Comment: The lib you posted sounds great, but will not work for me in this case. I'm using drawAtPoint:withFont, so i'm not using UILabels nor any similar resource.