# How can I create a UIFont with bold weight but not bold style?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uifont

In a UITableViewCellDefault style, the title font is a 20 point Helvetica normal-style font with a bold weight.  How can I create this same font in code?

I was thinking about creating an instance of UITableViewCell and copy it's font, but I won't be able to change the point size.

I found this on SO:
[Bold font with bold weight in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931541/bold-font-with-bold-weight-in-iphone)
but I'm looking for a regular font with bold weight.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the font name itself you can create them like so by using a dash:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Regular" size:12]
```

Comment: This creates a font with regular (not bold) style, but NOT bold weight.

Comment: If you want a bold weight use `@"Helvetica-Bold"`. There is no such thing as a regular font with bold weight. It's just a different weight value.